# Mockito: mock method parameter

Tags: java, testing, mocking

I am using Mockito framework for testing. Now I am having the following problem.

This is the class I want to test.

```
@Service
public class Parent{

   @Autowired
   private Child child;

   public void setChildDetails(ChildDetails childDetails){
      childDetails.validate();
      ....
      int age = childDetails.getAge();  
   }

}
```

This is my test.

```
public class ParentTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Parent parent;

    @Mock
    private Child child;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public testParentMethod(){
         .....
    }

    @Test
    public testChildDetailsMethod(){
        ChildDetails childDetails = new ChildDetails();
        childDetails.setAge(20);
        parent.setChildDetails(childDetails); 
    }

}
```

Mock for Child property do its job. The problem is that I want also to mock childDetails.validate() (only this method) and to leave other methods like they were (getAge() must return 20). Can you suggest how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you should use `spy`. Spy is a partual mock and will only mock the individual methods you tell it to. If `validate()` is a `void` method, you can use the `doNothing()` method for the spy. Use it as below:

```
   @Test
    public testChildDetailsMethod(){
       ChildDetailsSpy childSpy = spy(new ChildDetailsSpy());
       doNothing().when(childSpy).validate();
       childDetails.setAge(20);
       ...
   }
```

More reading about this subject can be found [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13).

Comment: Glad I could help. Please upvote and accept the answer by clicking the buttons to the left if it was helpful and sloved your problem :)